# JUnit 5 run a method after all tests in every class has run?

Tags: java, selenium, junit

I am trying to run a final method that does some logic after all my tests have completed running. I have seen the extension methods JUnit provides but they seem to all run after each test class

```
public class Watcher implements BeforeAllCallback, AfterAllCallback {
   public static boolean started = false;

   @Override
   public void beforeAll(ExtensionContext ec) throws Exception {
      if(!started) {
         started = true;
         // Some logic here and this works fine by using the static bool
         System.out.println("Started all");
      }   
   }

   @Override
   public void afterAll(ExtensionContext ec) throws Exception {
      // This runs after each test class I extend on 
         System.out.println("Finished all");
   }
}
```

// A Tests

```
public class ATest : BaseTest {
   @Test
   public void A() {
      System.out.println("A");
      assertTrue(true);
   }
}
```

// B Tests

```
public class BTest : BaseTest {
   @Test
   public void B() {
      System.out.println("B");
      assertTrue(true);
   }
}
```

// My watcher class

```
@ExtendWith(Watcher.class)
public class BaseTest {
   // Base test class stuff
}
```

It prints as

- Started all
- A
- Finished all
- B
- Finished all

But I want

- Started all
- A
- B
- Finished all

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do some stuff after all tests, you'll need to implement `ExtensionContext.Store.CloseableResource` instead of `AfterAllCallback`.

```java
public class Watcher implements BeforeAllCallback, ExtensionContext.Store.CloseableResource{
   public static boolean started = false;

   @Override
   public void beforeAll(ExtensionContext ec) throws Exception {
      if(!started) {
         started = true;
         // Some logic here and this works fine by using the static bool
         System.out.println("Started all");
      }   
   }


    @Override
    public void close() {
      // This runs after each test class I extend on 
         System.out.println("Finished all");
    }

}
```

If you need to execute this for every test class, then you could also use automatic extension registration. https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#extensions-registration-automatic
So your BaseTest can be removed.

Comment: My BaseTest class is initalizing the driver for each test and also quitting the driver after each test (along with taking a screenshot if the test fails) so I can just leave the ExtendWith for now

Comment: This doesn't work actually - this will run after each test class